# Are these local systems on $\mathscr{M}_{g,1}$ motivic?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, mapping-class-groups

Let $(\Sigma_g, x)$ be a pointed topological surface of genus $g$, and let $MCG(g,1)$ be the mapping class group of this pointed surface. Then $MCG(g,1)$ has a natural action on $\pi_1(\Sigma_g, x)$ $$MCG(g)\to \text{Aut}(\pi_1(\Sigma_g))$$ and hence acts on the set of irreducible characters of $\pi_1(\Sigma_g)$: $$\gamma: MCG(g,1)\to \text{Aut}(\text{Char}^{\text{irr}}(\pi_1(\Sigma_g))).$$

Suppose $$\rho: \pi_1(\Sigma_g)\to GL_n(\mathbb{C})$$ is an irreducible representation of $\pi_1(\Sigma_g)$ which is fixed by this action, i.e. for every element $\tau$ of $MCG(g,1)$, there exists a matrix $\varphi_\rho(\tau)$ conjugating $\rho^\tau$ to $\rho$ as a representation of $\pi_1(\Sigma_g)$. Because $\rho$ is irreducible, $\varphi_\rho(\tau)$ is well-defined up to scaling, and so we obtain a natural projective representation $$\varphi_\rho: MCG(g,1)\to PGL_n(\mathbb{C}).$$ Choosing a representation of $PGL_n(\mathbb{C})$ (say, the adjoint representation), we obtain a representation of $MCG(g,1)$ and hence a local system on the moduli space of pointed curves $\mathscr{M}_{g,1}$.

> Are the local systems obtained this way motivic?

I know how to produce several examples of such $\rho$ fixed by $MCG(g,1)$ (e.g. using the Parshin trick) and in these examples the local systems in question are indeed motivic.

Of course this question is too hard as stated in this generality -- so it would be better to ask:

> Do the local systems thus obtained underly $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$-variations of Hodge structure?

This question is naturally divided into three parts:

> 1. Is $\varphi_\rho$ always defined over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$? I.e. is it conjugate to a representation into $PGL_n(\overline{\mathbb{Q}})$?
> 2. Is $\varphi_\rho$ always integral, i.e. is it conjugate to a representation into $PGL_n(\overline{\mathbb{Z}})$?
> 3. Does $\text{ad}_{PGL_n}\circ \varphi_\rho$ always underly a $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$-variation of Hodge structure?

The only method of proof I can think of at the moment would be to show that $\varphi_\rho$ is *rigid* (which would imply (1) and (3), using non-abelian Hodge theory) or *cohomologically rigid* (which would imply (1-3) via recent results of Esnault and Groechenig). I haven't had any luck showing this thus far.

---

Some brief remarks on this old question (9/11/22):

1. As written, the answer is "no": I know how to make counterexamples for $g\leq 2$. Indeed, for $g\leq 2$ one may construct such local systems which do not have quasi-unipotent mondoromy at infinity. It's possible that the answer is "yes" in $g\leq 2$ if one additionally assumes this.
2. Such examples are impossible for $g\geq 3$, as any local system on $\mathscr{M}_{g,n}$ automatically has quasi-unipotent monodromy at infinity in this case by a result of Aramayona-Souto.
3. The answer is "yes" for representations of rank $r<\sqrt{g+1}$ with finite orbit under $MCG(g,1)$ by one of the results of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.15352) of mine and Landesman. This is because such representations necessarily have finite image.

Comment: In the $\ell$-adic world, if $\rho$, $\pi_1(\Sigma_g) \to GL_n( \overline{\mathbb Q}_\ell)$ factors continuously through the profinite completion of $\Sigma_g$, and this factorized representation is stable under the action of the arithmetic fundamental group of the moduli space of curves, then I think by the same construction we get a projective arithmetic representation. Of course by the grand theory of motives we expect variations of Hodge sructures and arithmetic representations should appear at the same time.

Comment: With regards to showing at least the first couple of your three points, might it make sense to show that $\rho$ has these properties first? I think if $\rho$ is algebraic or integral then $\varphi_{\rho}$ is algebraic or integral as well. For algebraicity at least a plausible avenue of proof is to show that $\rho$ has no 1-parameter deformations that respect this invariance property.

Comment: I agree with everything you’ve written—I tried the strategy in your second comment at some point but didn’t have any luck there either...some things are known in the case of 2-dimensional reps IIRC (due to Goldman and collaborators, for example), but not much.

Comment: Your construction of a representation does not really work since you are trying to act via $Aut(\pi_1(\Sigma))$ instead of $Out(pi_1(\Sigma))$. What you are actually getting here are projective representations of $MCG(g,1)$. I am sure, these are non-motivic in general and there are nontrivial families of (equivalence classes ) such representations. One more thing: Each fixed point $[\rho]$ does get you a  linear representation of $MCG(g)$ but in a different dimension: You act on the Zariski tangent space to the character variety at the point $[\rho]$.

Comment: You’re right, fixed. Do you know how to make such a nontrivial family?

Comment: It might be an easier project to show that, if $\rho$ is rigid as a representation satisfying this additional condition, then $\varphi_{\rho}$ is motivic, and if $\rho$ is not rigid then $\varphi_\rho$ is not (always) motivic. Determining whether $\rho$ is / isn't always rigid could be a separate matter.

Comment: @WillSawin: It seems to me that such reps will always be rigid as projective reps of the mapping class group, so at least (1) and (3) should be OK. And I think (2) should be OK by Esnault-Groechenig if the mapping class group action on the tangent space to $\rho$ has no invariants...

Comment: This seems very arbitrary to me. Why not ask if all representations of $M_{g,n}$ are motivic? But they're not all rigid. If you had a nonrigid representation of $M_{g,1}$, you could restrict to $\pi_1(\Sigma_g)$ and check if it remained irreducible. But I don't know any representations of $M_{g,1}$. For example, the Burau representation of $M_{0,n}^1$ is not rigid and probably remains irreducible when restricted to $\pi_1(P^1-n))$. (But it sounds motivic.)

Comment: @BenWieland: I should have assumed $g\geq 2$ -- the hope was that this construction rigidifies things, and it's motivated by some arithmetic considerations I omitted from the question, but which I can expand on if you'd like. Do you know of an example of a non-rigid representation of $\pi_1(M_{g,n})$ for some $g\geq 2$? Re: reps of $\pi_1(M_{g, 1})$, the Parshin trick gives examples, and there are others coming from TQFT's...

Comment: Yes, expand . . $M_2$ is virt $M_{0,6}$, so admits non-rigid reps. So ask $g\geqslant3$, but why stop there? Why did you think that 2 was enough? I don't really know any non-rigid reps, but here are two ideas. (1) a Burau-ish rep of $M_g$ on the homology of the abelian cover, as a $\mathbb Z[t_1,...t_{2g}]$-mod. (2) The rep of of $M_{g,1}$ on the Lie algebra of the 2-step nilpotent quotient of the fundamental group of the curve: shouldn't a 2-step nilpotent Lie algebra have a defm towards splitting, natural enough that it carries the rep? What happens when you restrict $M_{g,1}$ to $\pi_1S_g$?

Comment: Oops, my (2) is not reducible as an $M_{g,1}$ representation. That was the whole point, yet it ruins it. The whole point is that it is the degeneration of an extension to a split extension, but such degenerations are trivial away from the split locus.

Comment: @BenWieland: (1) is an interesting idea -- I'll play with it a bit and see what I get. Thanks!